# How to format number to custom string using regexp or function?

Tags: javascript

I need to convert a number to output string format. I need to set a number of decimals, decimal separator, and thousand separator.

I already have a function like this:

```
function (number, decimals, decPoint, thousandsSep) {
    var i, j, kw, kd, km;
    if (isNaN(decimals = Math.abs(decimals))) {
        decimals = 2;
    }
    if (decPoint == undefined) {
        decPoint = ",";
    }
    if (thousandsSep == undefined) {
        thousandsSep = "";
    }
    var sign = number  3) {
        j = j % 3;
    } else {
        j = 0;
    }
    km = (j ? i.substr(0, j) + thousandsSep : "");
    kw = i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + thousandsSep);
    kd = (decimals ? dec_point + Math.abs(number - (sign + i)).toFixed(decimals).replace(/-/, 0).slice(2) : "");
    return sign + km + kw + kd;
}
```

But I need to know, is there a faster or simplier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way which works in all browsers except safari `number.toLocaleString()` . For safari you can use your function and `toLocaleString()` for chrome firefox and ie

Comment: `toLocaleString` round the number to 3 decimal points when I test it in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach to your problem.

```
function transform(number, decimals, decPoint, thousandsSep) {
    var splitted = Math.abs(number).toFixed(isNaN(decimals) ? 2 : +decimals).split('.'),
        getSignPart = function (number) {
            return number < 0 ? ['-'] : [];
        },
        getIntPart = function (intPartStr, thousandsSep) {
            var res = intPartStr.split(''), idx;
            for (idx = intPartStr.length - 3; idx > 0; idx -= 3) {
                res.splice(idx, 0, thousandsSep);
            }
            return res;
        },
        getDecPart = function (decPartStr, decPoint) {
            return decPartStr ? [decPoint, decPartStr] : [];
        };

    return getSignPart(number)
            .concat(getIntPart(splitted[0], thousandsSep || ''))
            .concat(getDecPart(splitted[1], decPoint || ','))
            .join('');
}
```

First, I transform the number in a string with the desired number of decimals (if not specified, it defaults to 2). In js, the `.` is the default separator for decimals so I split using `.` in order to get the integer/decimal part of the number. Then, I add thousandSeparator (defaults to `''`) every 3 numbers and add decimalSeparator (if it is required and defaults to `,`).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would use toFixed for converting the number to a string with the desired decimals,

place the thousands separator piping the number from the right into an array separating in groups of 3,

at the end join everything together:

```js
var num = 1234567.543;


function formatNum(n,decimals,tSep,dSep){
   if(isNaN(n)) return;

  var r = n.toFixed(decimals || 0)
  var dec = r.match(/\.[0-9]*$/) ? ((dSep || '.') + r.match(/(?!\.)[0-9]*$/)[0]) : '';

  var int =  Math.floor(n).toString() //if you use this for negative numbers use truncation (n | 0) instead of Math.floor(n)
  var intSep = int.split('').reduceRight((ac, x) => {
    if (!ac[0] || ac[0].length === 3)
      ac.unshift([x]);
    else
      ac[0].unshift(x);
    return ac
  },[])
  .map(x => x.join(''))
  .join(tSep || '')
      
  return intSep + dec;
}

console.log(
  formatNum(num, 2,"'",",")
  )
```